# Why "textbook examples" of solutions to Schrodinger equation only deal with electrons?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, wavefunction, schroedinger-equation

Whenever studying first courses of quantum mechanics, the Schrodinger eqaution is always illustrated by an electron in some kind of a potential, and the solution (wavefunction) represents probability. But is it possible for example to solve the Schrodinger equation for a quarks (proton) - electron system? Or instead of solving for an electron in the potential of a proton, is it possible to solve for a proton in a potential of an electron?

Comment: What do you mean, as in an electron in the potential of a proton?

Comment: The Schroedindger equation is also used in nuclear physics for potential problems where the constituents are not relativistic, that would, however, not apply to quarks. The problem with quarks inside protons is that the layman's explanation that there are exactly three quarks in a proton which are held together by half a dozen gluons or so, is patently oversimplifying (I admit that even I believe it for a long time!). The quarks in a proton are highly relativistic (i.e. their kinetic energy is far higher than their rest mass), which requires a full quantum field theoretical treatment.

Comment: There are other applications in solid state physics, quantum optics, chemistry, etc. in which other types of particles (atoms, ions, neutrons, quasiparticles) are involved, the neutron fountain, for instance, was discussed in my introductory class to quantum mechanics, but I guess it depends on the lecturer/textbook author what material to include. Having said that, this is, on some level, a question for my opinion about what to include in a syllabus (I would include them all, especially for beginners, so they don't get stuck with your question), so I am not going to make this an answer.

Comment: First thing to say, it's a great question. Long story short, the first time I saw the S.E., I thought, having read the popular science books, where's the spin, the electric charge, how can they all fit in that little equation? So  to answer your question in the title, the electron is used (usually in one dimension) as an excellent teaching example  and then quantum mechanics is taught using it for a year, often using 3D methods and putting the S.E. into spherical coordinates etc. I sincerely apologise if this is already familiar to you, I am not sure what level of study you are at.

Comment: The title asks a completely dfferent question from the body, and it is not actually clear what you want to know - quantum mechanics as such makes no statement about the kind of particles/objects it works for.

Comment: In addition to lack of clarity in the question, this appears to be a list-based question (which is also off-topic).

Comment: @ACuriousMind, I improved the question.

Comment: @KyleKanos, what's a "list-based question"?

Comment: @Sparkler: A list-based question is one in which the answer is essentially a list. We prefer our questions to be *conceptual* in nature and list-based questions rarely fit that category. Since your modifications change this, I've voted to reopen the question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Schrodinger equation is an approximation because it ignores relativistic effects and it ignores spin. However, aside from these limits it applies to any system and not just electrons. The trouble is that the Schrodinger equation, and indeed most partial differential equations, are impossible to solve except in a few special cases. Since we have no special desire to melt the brains of new students we generally start by describing those special cases.

The solutions for electrons are a convenient starting point for various reasons. Electrons are light, so we can approximate them as moving in static potential e.g. in an atom or molecule we the nuclei are so much heavier than electrons that [we assume they are fixed in place](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Born%E2%80%93Oppenheimer_approximation) when calculating the electron wavefunction. Most of chemistry can be explained by just calculating the wavefunctions for electrons moving around static nuclei. We can also get a pretty accurate answer by treating the electrons as moving in an average potential, so we reduce an insoluble many body problem to [an approximately soluble single body problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hartree%E2%80%93Fock_method).

If we take your example of a nucleus, this is a very difficult problem. The strong force that holds nuclei together can't be described by a non-relativistic equation. Even if it we ignore the detail and use some approximate potential for the strong force, we have a many body system that isn't amenable to the sorts of simplifications we can use in atoms. In fact a full description of the structure of nuclei is beyond us even using our most advanced theories.

Comment: even when using a [relativistic hamilotnian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relativistic_quantum_mechanics#Non-relativistic_and_relativistic_Hamiltonians) the Schrodinger eq. is still only an approximation?

Comment: @Sparkler: if you use a relativistic Hamiltonian you get the Klein–Gordon or Dirac equations not the Schrodinger equation.